# Trying to change the color of a ellipse's in array, in p5.js after time has passed, but get error: "TypeError: color is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, colors, p5.js

Trying to make a simulator for COVID-19, after some time after a person in my simulation gets infected, i want them to recover, and this to be shown by changing the color of the person to change to pink.

This is what i am trying to do so far:

```
setRecoveredTimer() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            let newColor = '#d176d6';
            this.isRecovered = true;
            this.color = color(newColor);
        }, 5000);
}
```

Whenever the 5 seconds has passed, i get this error:

[TypeError: color is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFFdo.png)

I am able to change color other places is my code, like here:

```
changeColor() {
        if (this.isInfected == true) {
            this.color = color('#ed2d2d');
        }
    }
```

If it is any help, the rest of my project is here: https://github.com/perkynades/Simulation-of-COVID19/tree/part1

Been stuck on this issue for a day now, so any help will be appriciated :)

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Try linking to a simplified sketch in the p5.js editor or CodePen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do this?

```
setRecoveredTimer() {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            let newColor = '#d176d6';
            this.isRecovered = true;
            this.color = color(newColor);
        }, 5000);
}
```

The ES6 Arrow syntax ()=>{} is the same as function(){}, but it keeps the 'this' from where it is initialized. In the case above; the 'this' is the class where setRecoveredTimer exists.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thank you, This just save my exam!

Comment: Sweet :) I've actually edited the answer and added why it works , with a link.

Comment: This worked for a solution for a p5js problem i was having to trying to use color inside a homemade function. weird. thanks for the tip